# How to grab a specific value from a core data saved array swift

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data

Basically, instead of pulling the most recent saved object, I'd like to pull out previously saved objects. How would I go about doing this? What the code is doing is setting the text of a label depending on the object's text pulled from the array, but I want to pull older saves.

```
// deleteAllRecords()   // ---- uncomment deleteAllRecords() here to delete all records saved.
    // FETCH BLOCK
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Tasks")

    //request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "age = %@", "12")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        for data in result as! [Tasks] {
            print(data.value(forKey: "taskName"))
            if let reminders = data.value(forKey: "taskName") as? [Reminder] {
                for reminder in reminders {
                    // Now you have your single object Reminder and you can print his variables
                    print("Your reminder description is \(reminder.reminderDescription), and his length is \(reminder.reminderLength)")
                    self.reminderDisplay.text = reminder.reminderDescription
                    if reminderDisplay.text == reminder.reminderDescription {
                        self.testLabel1.text = reminder.reminderDescription
                        reminderCount = 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How would I go about doing this? 
Thanks in advance. - Sav.

**EDIT:**

```
  // SAVE BLOCK
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Tasks", in: context)
    let newTask = Tasks(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    newTask.setValue(reminderList, forKey: "taskName")

    do {
        try context.save()

    } catch {
        print("Failed saving")
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "taskName = %@", "Lock the door.")
```

**EDIT3:**

Here's the object code;

```
public class Reminder: NSObject, NSCoding {

var reminderDescription : String? = nil
var reminderLength : Int? = nil// in days

public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.reminderDescription = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "reminderDescription") as? String
    self.reminderLength = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "reminderLength") as? Int
}

public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(reminderDescription, forKey: "reminderDescription")
    aCoder.encode(reminderLength, forKey: "reminderLength")
}

init (chosenReminderDescription: String, chosenReminderLength: Int) {
    reminderDescription = chosenReminderDescription
    reminderLength = chosenReminderLength

}
```

}

[Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1IZn.png)

If possible I'd like to query in relation to when they were made, like the first one, then the 2nd one. Would I have to give the object a date property and query through that?

**EDIT4:**

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "orderNo = %@", "2")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        for data in result as! [Tasks] {
            print(data.value(forKey: "taskName"))
            if let reminders = data.value(forKey: "taskName") as? [Reminder] {
                for reminder in reminders {
                    // Now you have your single object Reminder and you can print his variables
                    print("Your reminder description is \(reminder.reminderDescription), and his length is \(reminder.reminderLength)")
                    self.reminderDisplay.text = reminder.reminderDescription
                    if reminderDisplay.text == reminder.reminderDescription {
                        self.testLabel1.text = reminder.reminderDescription
                        reminderCount = 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to call a request at entity ***Task*** and get the results in an Array correctly.
I would suggest you to look if you are actually saving the previous attempts to store value at your Core Data entity ***Task*** before asking for queries like this.

Don't forget that sometimes Core Data decides to postpone actual storing of information on its DB.

So try forcing savings into CoreDB before querying. For this to happen, make sure you are calling ".save()" to guarantee that Core Data sends (and executes) a saving request right away.

A sample code to force saving right away is down below:

```
do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Failure to save context: \(error)")
    }
}
```

–

**Edit (24/11/2018 03:07AM GMT+01:00):**

By reading your comment, it looks like you just want to filter the queries for a specific value, instead of querying the most recent ones.
To do so, just simply uncomment the code:

```
  //request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "age = %@", "12")
```

To:

```
  request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "age = %@", "12")
```

Inside the NSPredicate's format method calling is supposed to be what you want as the statement of your filtering. If you want to filter it by age, your example is already done for you.

I'll also attach an example of other codes of mine.

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(time >= %@) AND (time <= %@)", fromDateUnformatted as NSDate, toDateUnformatted as NSDate)
```

Now if you want to do relationship-related queries (double or more queries at once to dig information further inside Entities' relationships), then there are other methods of doing so.

Let me know if I'm going in the right direction to find an answer.

Comment: I have a save function in place.  I'll edit it and show you, it is saving, I have it dumping and printing the previous saved information, I just want to be able to pull specific saves, not jsut the most recent if that is possible.

Comment: Got it. I'll edit the answer so that I'll include more information regarding pulling specific saves...

Comment: I've tried to implement the predicate line, but I cant seem to query correctly. The reminder object has two properties, if I wanna for instance, query the 2nd saved object and it's property that is a string, how would I go about that? Thanks for the help Luke.

Comment: This is how I'm trying to query it, refer to the 2nd edit.

Comment: When querying, you should look for a specific information to seek in that Task Entity that is carrying the Reminder object and two properties of it. What does this 2nd object have, differently than the 1st saved object, that make you want it? It is the name, or the date, or other different thing entirely? You need to query it by something. The predicate would be similar to the WHERE suffix in a Database SQL language. I would need a little more information to be able to help you completely: Can you post at your question the Core Data Model related to this Task element?

Comment: Reading the EDIT2, I see now that you want to query the Task Name as a String. The only information still missing for me to be able to 100% help you is to know a little bit how the structure of your Task object is. How did you model it? With this information I think I'll be able to help construct your predicate correctly.

Comment: I edited, showing the object Reminder and linked the data model.

Comment: Reading EDIT3, I see that you are right that it is missing some link information to query these reminders back again later. There are at least two ways you can do this: (1) by adding another variable on your Tasks Entity indicating this order. It can be an order number (orderNo) or the date the order was made (orderDate), for example. Then, you query it by looking for an order that matches the order number or date.Or (2) is for you to actually create the Reminder as another entity inside your Core Data Model. And link with a relationship the Reminder entity to the Tasks one. And query from it.

Comment: Okay. I've tried to implement the orderNo. I'm trying to query the orderNo = 2. Is this correct? request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "orderNo = %@", "2")

Comment: It doesn't seem to print the description and length of the desired task, nothing is printed. I'll edit and show the entire process.

Comment: It's actually causing a crash. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath orderNo not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Tasks id=1>' 
Then I tried changing the orderNo in the query to taskName and it doesn't crash but it doesn't query anything.

Comment: Are you re-compiling (re-generating) the Core Data Model into a new fresh DB after it? And Adding the actual TaskNo key/value pair when inserting and saving info into the your Core Data DB? It appears to be an error of invalid argument "oderNot" not being found on your Task's Entity structure.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what that comprises of so no. How would I go about adding it to the entity structure?

Comment: You would have to delete the classes you automatically generated using Xcode and generate them all again. Here are two links explaining this: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/core-data-code-generation/
 and https://medium.com/@kahseng.lee123/core-data-codegen-explained-462c30341041

Comment: I've been busy and haven't had the chance to get around to it. If I come back to this in the future I'll let you know. Thanks heaps man.